# best way to implement one-to-many realationships in mongoDb

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, one-to-many

most of systems has some users that do something (order, participate in exams, fill some forms and etc) and there are information that related to user that are in user collection. for example age.
assume an order system:

if we keep only userId in orders collection and try to get count of orders that are made by users under 25 in a specific time range is some sort of impossible. (mongodb aggregation performance is so bad and its not working as expected).

if we keep user object in orders collection, our database grows enormous. but the query with user fields is possible.

so, what is the best way to keep these kind of information. is there a third way ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have an orders collection in every user object. SO to get a count of orders for every user that is under 25 for example you'll just have to count the user objects that have the age attribute be <25 and find the SUM the number of orders in each orders collection from every user object.

I would do this because it is more maintainable number of users will always be <= number of orders, so if won't be that enormous as per your approach of keeping user object inside order object.

Comment: tnx for your answer, you mean keeping user activity in user collection plus the other collection? (in this example the other collection is order) it wont be so much info in user collection ? what about search performance in user collection? it doesnt get effect ?!

Comment: Search performance won't be affected. 
Something like
{
user_id: 1,
name: "Stefan",
age: 24,
orders: { {order_id: 1, date_order:"2020-08-09", order_location:"Macedonia"}, {order_id: 2, date_order:"2020-08-10", order_location:"Serbia"}
},
{
user_id: 2,
name: "Bob",
age: 40,
orders: { {order_id: 3, date_order:"2018-08-09", order_location:"Slovenia"}
}
}